# Emoji not showing in gift card message

Tags: magento2, gift-card

When I add an emoji to the message I entered when purchasing a gift card, I cannot see this message. It can't be displayed in the person I gifted it to. You can view the steps I did in the sample picture.

Any solution on how I can fix this?

[image: Gift Card not Showing Emoji]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for responses . Here is the short solution.

Firstly change column charset in database:

```
ALTER TABLE `cleanmagento`.`quote_item_option` CHANGE `value` `value` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL COMMENT 'Value';
```

after to change this line in apt/etc/env.php

```
'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8mb4;',
```

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

make sure you are using **utf8mb4_general_ci** collation on your database.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to check out this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463134/how-to-store-emoji-character-in-mysql-database

[Emoji in Magento 2 frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/365283/emoji-in-magento-2-frontend)

Hope it helps to  you..!!